# google cloud storage/gsutil ls command inconsistent results

Tags: cloud, storage, gsutil

I am getting strange results when I move files using gsutil mv command in compute engine  from one folder in bucket to another folder in same bucket.
Sometime it shows files are moved and but other times files are not shown/moved. it happens both with gsutil ls command and from storage browser as well. I don't know is there any sync up/latency issue in GCS.

Usecase: I am writing very simple ETL process in linux script in compute engine to load files from GCS into bigquery tables and post load files must be moved to archive location in the GCS.

After script execution when I issue gsutil ls or in storage browser sometimes (keep executing gsutil ls command or refreshing the browser)  files are moved and other times it doesn't show the same

Any help on this issue is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Srinivas